# Python Gui Automation

Tags: python-3.x

I've been looking around for a few weeks trying to find a library to help fit my needs.

I'm looking for a way to create what would be as a secondary virtual keyboard / mouse cursor. It doesn't necessarily have to be visible per se, but the idea behind it is that I want to be able to have my normal cursor and keyboard free to be used, while the secondary virtual keyboard and mouse are used for automation in another window.

I'm not entirely sure where to begin on this journey... Any ideas, stackoverflow community?

Comment: Do you want to have two HIDs plugged in at the same time (two keyboards two mice) into the physical computer?

Comment: Preferably not. The entire idea is to be able to do what I want like browsing, or playing games or something, while I have a virtual setup that is automatically interacting with another background application.

Comment: You could interact with a literally virtual setup through the pyvirtualbox api. Would that work? I'm trying to figure out what the desired functionality is. Alt+ [TAB] will let you browse as the game runs in the background; but you want the opposite, you want the browser running in the background, is that right?

Comment: Hm. So, say for example you are playing any game on the machine. Naturally you would want the machines window focus to be on the game you're playing, else you're not properly interacting with the game and therefore would be interrupted. The intent is to be able to fully play the game without interruptions while this virtual set up is interacting with a background application. However, I'm not familiar with the pyvirtualbox api, but it sounds like if I'm able to attach a specified process within the "virtual box" it may solve my problem. As long as the hardware isn't changed during that.

Comment: Pyvirtualbox is a computer emulator. It virtualizes an entirely new machine as best it can from the motherboard back. You get an entire virtualized OS with this option. If all you want is uninterrupted gameplay you might want to look into writing an Overlay that interfaces with the game you wish to target, similar to the Discord or Overwolf overlays.

Comment: So the likelihood of being able to spawn an additional mouse cursor and assign it to a window is slim?

Comment: You would be doing the drawing, mouseover detection, and probably process spawning all by hand. I have looked into this previously myself, there have bee some solutions that spawned a new window fullscreen on a second monitor, but the mouse was just a jpeg tranitioned over the screen and was illusory; it wasn't a true cursor and was compared against with collisions in the gui thread of the app. It's not like you'd just plug in a few lines and be using chrome is what I'm saying. But that's just based on my independent research. Cpuld you post what you've tried so far? Ctypes.wintypes might help

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I've only been trying to find possible library solutions. I feel that this is a generic task that had to have been encountered before and am stumped that I haven't found any posts on it.

Comment: There are other methods of GUI automation, eg hotkeys. You can alt-tab or play in windowed mode. This question is just a little limited in usefulness, and unless you narrow it down to a specific set of behaviours I doubt you will find a library based solution but best of luck.

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how the question wasn't sufficient. I thoroughly described my intended desire which was **I am looking for a library that will aid in simulating mouse and keyboard input to an unfocused window**. If that doesn't describe what I'm looking for, then pleas elaborate where the confusion is. I read that pywinauto has issues sending keystrokes and mouse input to an unfocused or minimized window.

Comment: I don't think that anything short of actually trying it, posting your code, the outcome, the desired behaviour, the result behaviour, and how the result differs from the desired behaviour will be sufficient. Currently there is no well defined behaviour. Do you want the window minimized or unfocused? In your question you say you don't care if it is or isn't. So which is it then? What do you actually want to do? If it's just for browsing I think there might be a chromium API for python, and you could try that.